# Loading files into MAGMA

Tags: file, loading, symbolic-math

I'm trying to load files into MAGMA and am running into some trouble. Ostensibly, the command `load "filename";`should be sufficient. I've attempted, but keep getting the same result:

```
>> load "filename";
   ^
User error: Could not open file "filename" (No such file or directory)
```

The file is saved in my documents folder, so I'm not sure what the issue is. Do I have to specify the path? Save the file in a particular place?

I've tried reformatting, using both txt and rtf files, so I don't think that's the issue.

Answer (score 3):

For loading file in MAGMA you can place your file in installed place folder. For example: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Magma`

> Also if your file have an special format you should mention it.

Suppose You want loading a txt file with name `a`. with `load"a";` you face with error. You must type `load"a.txt";`.

Answer (score 1):

Try using GetCurrentDirectory() command to find your current directory location. And then you can use SetPath() to change where MAGMA has to be to search for your file. This will fix it.